# AS3.0 Hittest not registering

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, hittest

I'm having issue with a hittest not registering. I have two arrays of objects, ladderlist and blocklist. I'm checking if my main character, mainchar, hits any of the objects on the enterframe event with a nested loop. I have a boolean variable MCFall, which is supposed to change if it hits either object. The loop will break if MCFall is false, that is, if mainchar is hitting either a ladder or block. The problem I'm currently having is that my code can't detect if mainchar is hitting the block. Relevant code below.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_EnterFrameHandler);
function fl_EnterFrameHandler(event:Event):void{    
  //check if touching ANY ground
  blockCheckLoop: for (var i: int=0; i<=blocklist.length; i++){
    if (blocklist[i].target.hitTestObject(mainchar.target)){
      MCFall = false;
      MCmovespeed = 4;
    }//endif
    else{
      ladderCheckLoop: for (var j: int=0; j<=ladderlist.length;j++){
        if (ladderlist[j].target.hitTestObject(mainchar.target)){
          MCFall = false;
          MCmovespeed = 4;
        }//endif
        else{
          MCFall = true;
          MCmovespeed = 0;
        }//endelseif
        if(MCFall == false) break ladderCheckLoop;
      }//endforj*/
    }//endelseif
    if(MCFall == false) break blockCheckLoop;
  }//endfori
}//endenterframe
```

I have tested the hittest with blocklist without the loop checking if mainchar hits the ladder, which works. MCmovespeed is just a variable I use so that mainchar can't move sideways while falling. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The logic appears sound except I don't understand why you have nested for loops, why aren't these just side by side.  How you have it configured now, it will check a block then check all ladders, then check the next block and again check all ladders, seems just sweeping through each set would be sufficient.  As for what's wrong inspect blocklist, it seems it must contain some elements for the loop to be running at all but perhaps they don't have position/size correct for some reason.

Comment: I would drop a trace in the conditional for a blocklist hitTest, so that you can verify that a positive hitTest for a block is actually occurring. If so, then it's your break that is not executing correctly. The next step I would take is to put a breakpoint inside that same conditional and step through from there.

Answer (score 0):

You better use the following code:

for(var b:int = 0; b

```
var currentBlockList:blockList_class = new blocklistArray[b];
```

for(var m:int = 0; m

```
var currentMainChar:mainChar_class = new maincharArray[m];

if(currentBlockList.target).hitTestObject(currentMainChar.target)){

    trace("hit");
}
```

}
}